# Show that Th$(\mathfrak{A}_{n})$=Th$(\mathfrak{A}_{i})$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: logic, model-theory

Consider language $\mathcal{L}$ consisting of binary relation symbol <. Let $\mathfrak{A}_{0}$ be $\mathcal{L}$-structure with universe $A_{0}=\{0,1,\dots\}$.
Let $\mathfrak{A}_{n}$ be the $\mathcal{L}$-structure with universe $A_{n} := \{-n,\dots,-1,0,1,2,\dots\}$ with natural interpretation of <.

Show that Th$(\mathfrak{A}_{n})$=Th$(\mathfrak{A}_{i})$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am not sure how to show that formally. We have to show the elementary equivalence. The theory is the set of $\mathcal{L}$-sentences, so formulas without free variables. The only difference between the structures is the universe. So all the structures satisfy the same sentences, since sentences don't include any free variables and the relation symbol is always the same.

Am I missing something here or how could I write this up more formally?

Comment: in fact you can show much more than elementary equivalence; we have $\mathfrak{A}_n\cong\mathfrak{A}_i$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. can you see how?

Comment: in any case, to be formal you should use induction on the complexity of sentences

Comment: You seem to be missing the fact that sentences can contain quantified variables. Those variables range over all elements of the universe of the structure. So changing the universe can affect the meaning of the quantifcations in a sentence. (If your argument were correct, it would show that any structure and any substructure are elementarily equivalent, and that's not true.)

Comment: Interesting! Thank you guys! I will think it through again!

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom can you give me a hint on how to start such a proof?

Comment: @craft yes, absolutely! first I should make sure; are you familiar with the definition of an isomorphism in model theory? and have you seen the result that isomorphic structures are "elementarily equivalent" (ie satisfy the same sentences)? no worries at all if not; I'll write up an answer showing that result if you need to see it

Comment: I do. In lecture we defined an isomorphism as a surjective embedding. Embedding being $R^{\mathfrak{A}}(a_1, \dots, a_n })$ = $R^{\mathfrak{A}}(h(a_1), \dots, h(a_n) })$  and then $h$ is an isomorphism. $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ are structures in that case and R is a relation.

I feel like I have to work out an example for a structure such that I get the idea properly I think.

Thanks so much.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom could you give me some guidance there?

Comment: @craft great! okay, for a hint, consider the map $f_{ij}:\mathfrak{A}_i\rightarrow\mathfrak{A}_j$ given by $f_{ij}(n)=n+(i-j)$. to show that this is an isomorphism, you need to show that it is (a) a bijection, and (b) respects all of the function, constant, and relation symbols of $\mathcal{L}$. for task (b), remember that, in this case, $\mathcal{L}$ has only one symbol ("<"), so this is the only one you need to check

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom For fixed i and j I can construct $f_{ij}(n)^{-1}=n-i+j$ which is the inverse, which shows this is a bijection. And b) I will try now.

Comment: As for respect to the functions probably I have to show $f_{ij}(f^{A_{i}}(a_{1},\dots ,a_{n})) = f^{A_{j}}(f_{ij}(a_{1}).\dots f_{ij}(a_{n}) )$ right, where f is some function from the structure? Maybe it would be easier if you could write the solution, not sure

Comment: @craft you're very nearly there!! basically, the main point is that there are *no* function symbols in the language $\mathcal{L}$. indeed, $\mathcal{L}=\{<\}$ has only one symbol! namely, the relation symbol "$<$". so, to show that $f_{ij}$ is an $\mathcal{L}$-embedding, we just need to show that $f_{ij}$ respect "$<$" – ie, that, if $n<m\in A_i$, then $f_{ij}(n)<f_{ij}(m)\in A_j$. do you think you can show that now?

Comment: Ok that would be then just $f_{ij}(m) < f_{ij}(n)$ which is $m+(i-j)<n+(i-j)$ and hence $m<n$. Ok so constants and functions we dont have so that is enough if I understand correctly.

Comment: yes, exactly! :) so, to sum up, $f_{ij}$ is a bijective $\mathcal{L}$-embedding, ie an isomorphism, so $\mathfrak{A}_i$ and $\mathfrak{A}_j$ are isomorphic and hence in particular elementarily equivalent.

Comment: Great! Thank you soo much :)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I would have another question. I have to find a $\forall\exists$ sentence $\phi$ such that $\mathfrak{B}\models \phi$ but $\mathfrak{A}_{0} \not\models \phi$, where $\mathfrak{B}=\cup_{i \in \mathbb{N} } \mathfrak{A}_{i}$. So I need to find a sentence that is satisfied in one but not oin the other. I was thinking for example that in B Structure every element would have an inverse but I dont have any function to my disposal so how can I construct such a statement? Or is there something more clever I have to do?

Comment: @craft here's a hint: given $n\in B$, you can always find an element of $B$ that is strictly less than $n$. (just take $n-1$.) is this true in any $\mathfrak{A}_i$? and can you find a way to express this property as an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence?

Comment: Ah of course. Why didnt I think about it. So I guess that would be $\forall n \exists m (m<n)$ ?

Comment: @craft yep! exactly :)

Comment: The last thing I have to show would be that Th($\mathfrak{A}_{0}$) is inductive. Sorry thats the last question. Would that be something that has to be solved in the same vein as the original question?

Comment: hmm, what's your definition of "inductive" here?

Comment: We defined a theory as inductive when the union of any directed family of models of T is again a model of T.

Comment: hmm, are you sure that the problem claims that $\text{Th}(\mathfrak{A}_0)$ is inductive? for instance, the $(\mathfrak{A}_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ form a directed family of models of $\text{Th}(\mathfrak{A}_0)$, but, as you've just shown, its union $\mathfrak{B}$ actually is not a model of $\text{Th}(\mathfrak{A}_0)$!

Comment: Ah yeah you are right. It actually was a question if the theory is inductive, not a claim. Thanks!